# "Modules" is not allowed Error

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Webpack 2 comes with the new resolve setting and when I try to modify the setting in config, as follows, webpackValidator throws an error saying

> **"Modules" is not allowed"**

[image: Error in Terminal]

```
const config = webpackValidator({

    context: resolve('src'),
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: resolve('dist'),
      publicPath: '/dist/',
      pathinfo: ifNotProd(),
    },
    devtool: ifProd('source-map', 'eval'),
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loaders: ['babel'],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js'],
      modules: [
        resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new DashboardPlugin()
    ]
  })
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned on the webpack-validator project's readme ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-validator) & [github](https://github.com/js-dxtools/webpack-validator)), you should seriously consider giving up the use of this package...

> Note: webpack v2 has built-in validation for configuration. Due to this, webpack-validator is unlikely to make significant changes. While pull requests will be reviewed and can be merged, project maintainers are unlikely to put a lot of much effort into the maintenance of the project.

I had the same issue and finally gave up its use : Webpack 2 introduced breaking changes that surely won't be followed by the webpack-validator project.
The new built-in validation for configuration in Webpack 2 is now good enough.

By the way, your config may need a few improvements :

```
const config = {

context: resolve('src'),
entry: './app.js',
output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: resolve('dist'),
  publicPath: '/dist/',
  pathinfo: ifNotProd(),
},
devtool: ifProd('source-map', 'eval'),
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: ['babel-loader'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }
  ]
},
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js'],
  modules: [
    resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
  ]
},
plugins: [
  new DashboardPlugin()
]
}
```

- `module.loaders` becomes `module.rules`
- `module.loaders.loaders` becomes `module.rules.use`
- You can't use the shortcut 'babel' instead of 'babel-loader' any more, unless you specify it (`resolveLoader.moduleTemplates` property).

Comment: this answer not really help users